# Redirect on click If JavaScript is disabled, otherwise check the child radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `radio` `button` within a link:

```
<label class="dd--option">
    <a href="someURL" class="dd--noscript--link">
        <input name="dd_radio" type="radio" class="dd--radio dd--radio--js" checked />
        <span class="dd--label">
            <img class="dd--label--image" src="http://90.0.0.91/show.php/swatch/23080/black"/>
            <span class="dd--label--text">Black</span>
        </span>
    </a>                    
</label>
```

I want to achieve the following:

- If JavaScript is disabled on browser, I want to redirect to the link given in `href` `attribute` of the `anchor tag`.
- If JavaScript is enabled, It should not redirect anywhere. It should only check the `radio` `button`.

Can I able to achieve it? If Yes, How ?

Comment: So add href to the anchor and cancel the click with JavaScript.

Comment: Just write a script that does what you want to happen when JS is enabled. If JS is disabled, it will be ignored, and clicking on the anchor will follow the link.

Comment: @Barmar I put # as a placeholder here.

Comment: The question would be clearer if you used something that looks like a placeholder -- `#` is normally used for links that are *not* supposed to go anywhere. Something like `href="someURL"`

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if the clicking on an `<input>` will automatically bubble event up to a parent `<a>` in every browser, but if so, this should do it:

```
$('.dd--noscript--link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As @Barmar mentioned in the comments, with JS disabled, `href="#"` would not cause the browser to load a new page.

Comment: He added a comment saying that `href="#"` was just meant as a placeholder in the question, the real code will have a URL there. I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Javascript event handler on the radio button, and use `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
$(".dd--radio--js").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If Javascript is enabled, this function will be executed, and `stopPropagation()` will prevent the click from bubbling to the anchor, so it won't follow the link.

If Javascript is disabled, this code won't be executed, so the click will bubble out to the anchor, and the link will be followed.

Comment: This works, but if you have any other clickable elements withing the `<a>` (`<img>`, `<span>`, `<label>`, etc), you might want to `stopPropogation()` from those as well.

Comment: @jmorganmartin Those elements don't have any default click action, so it's only necessary if you have added click handlers to them. Your answer is probably better, as it's independent of what's inside.